# HTML file is loading partially

Tags: html, mean-stack

I am using MEAN stack for development and here is the following code

```
app.use('/admin', function (req, res, next) {
//check if admin is login or not, if not then render login page else admin page
   if (req.session.user && req.session.user.type == 'admin') {
       res.sendFile(__dirname + '/frontend/admin.html');
   }
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/frontend/adminLogin.html');
});

app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/frontend/index.html');
});
```

I want to render adminLogin.html file if adminuser is not logged in and if there is adminuser present is session then I want to render admin.html.
Now the issue is that after login, my admin.html is partially loading, means only 70 lines are loading everytime.

So can any one tell me that what is the issue and if any one has any other solution to access admin panel then please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you don't exit after the `if` and therefore you are sending both `admin.html` and `adminLogin.html`

It should be:

```
if (req.session.user && req.session.user.type == 'admin') {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/frontend/admin.html');
    return;
}
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/frontend/adminLogin.html');
```

Of alternatively:

```
if (req.session.user && req.session.user.type == 'admin')
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/frontend/admin.html');
else
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/frontend/adminLogin.html');
```